# C#のクラスライブラリについて

Tags: c#

Visual studio2013でクラスライブラリを作成しようと考えています。

新しいプロジェクトでクラスライブラリを選択してプロジェクトを作成、新しい項目の追加でClass2.csを追加しました。そしてビルドをしてdllを作成しました。
次に、新しいプロジェクトでコンソールアプリケーションを選択してプロジェクトを作成、参照の追加で先ほど作成したdllを追加しました。
その結果、コンソールアプリケーションのプロジェクトでデフォルトで生成されるClass1は認識できるのですが、後から自分で追加したClass2は見つからずコンパイルエラーとなります。

このような現象について何か考えられることはありますか
よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 7, accepted):

おだんさんが、追加されたClass2に、publicアクセス修飾子は付いていますでしょうか？

```
public class Class2{...}
```

このようにしないと、自分のアセンブリの外方から見えなくなります。

```
class Class2{...}
```

と書いた場合は、

```
internal class Class2{...}
```

と同じ意味になるので、アセンブリ内で参照可能でも、アセンブリ外では参照できず、コンパイルエラーとなります。

その点を確かめてみてはいかがでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

Class2を使用するファイルの一番上にusing句を追加してみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
using SampleClassLibrary;
```